# Parsing indented text with Boost Spirit

Tags: c++, boost-spirit

I'd like to parse a text file with the tree structure define by indentations such as: (added types in parenthesis to give idea of types)

```
A1 (string)
  elem1 20 30 40 (string, float, float, float)
  elem2 10 70
  elem3 12           (string,float)
  elem4 10 70 13
A2
  elem1 42 77
  elem2  4 31 23
```

I wonder what would be the most optimal way (from the maintainability standpoint) to parse the file into a data structure?

At the moment I'm considering Boost Spirit or regex to do the job but leaning towards the former.  This is the first time I will try to use Spirit and it is not 100% clear if it is the right tool for the job. Regex on the other hand may be more flexible to work with heterogenous, non-uniform data.
Any suggestions are much appreciated.